# How to specify a command to clean a custom cmake target?

Tags: cmake

I have made a custom target in cmake by using `add_custom_target` and it compiles some HLSL shaders for me. However, when I clean the target using visual studio it does not delete the compiled files. How do I specify a command to delete the compiled shader files?

Comment: Please show your CMake code. Most likely, you need to list the commands output files somewhere, like in `OUTPUTS` of `add_custom_command` or `BYPRODUCTS`

Comment: can't you just make another custom target that deletes those files and invoke the target with `cmake --build <build_dir> --target <cleaner_target>`?